# PHPunit После выполнения 355 тестов, следующие выполняются очень долго, почему?

Tags: php, macos, phpunit

Перешел с ubuntu на MacBook (соответственно на macOS).
На Ubuntu 1500 тестов выполнялись быстро, а после того как перенес проект на мак тесты стали выполняться супер долго.
Если один тест запустить то он выполнится быстро, а если запустить все тесты то первые 355 выполнятся быстро а все остальные очень долго (доходит до 10 мин один тест).
Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с таким? Может я что-то не настроил?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: проклятый мак, всегда с ним какие-то приколы. Отпишите пожалуйста в конце концов, что было, и как вы решили.